# Docker image with mysql and .war file on ECS

Tags: mysql, docker, amazon-ec2, dockerfile, war

I am totally new in Docker community and I am trying to create a custom container image with *mysql* and a *.war* file inside and to run it on a AWS EC2 instance. I've tried a lot but I cannot figure this out..

- To build the container image I rum this

`docker build -t <name-of-image> -f Dockerfile`

- I suppose Docker file content should contain something like

```
FROM mysql:latest

ENV TARGETD /opt/apache-tomcat-9.0.35
ENV WAR /target/NewWebApp.war

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get -y upgrade

# Create database
RUN mkdir /usr/sql
#RUN CHMOD 644 /usr/sql

ADD db.sql /usr/sql/db.sql

RUN mysql -h localhost -P 3306 --protocol=tcp -u root start  && \
mysql -u root -e < /usr/sql/db.sql

EXPOSE 3306

ADD ${WAR} ${TARGETD}/webapps
```

- And to run(deploy) image I use

`docker run -d -p 8080:3306 <name-of-image>:latest`

**I have already installed Tomcat on 8080**

What can I do in order to run this image and to be able to access it through AWS EC2?

Comment: Can you take all of the database-related parts out of the image?  (Running multiple processes in a container adds a lot of complication and data-persistence requirements, and in general you can't run database-setup commands from a Dockerfile in any case.)  Either run a separate MySQL container or run MySQL in RDS, and run migrations either at container startup or manually.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this way.